# Python3 Requests not using passed-in proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, network-programming, python-requests

Requests isn't using the proxies I pass to it. The site at the url I'm using shows which ip the request came from--and it's always my ip not the proxy ip. I'm getting my proxy ips from sslproxies.org which are supposed to be anonymous.

```
    url = 'http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test'
    proxies = {'http': 'x.x.x.x:xxxx'}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla...etc'}

    res = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
```

Are there certain headers that need to be used or something else that needs to be configured so that my ip is hidden from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) state

> that proxy URLs must include the scheme.

Where scheme is `scheme://hostname`. So you should add 'http://' or 'socks5://' to your proxy URL, depending on the protocol you're using.

Comment: You put me in the right directions. Requests is still behaving funny. When I use 'https' as the key it doesn't go through proxy (even though the proxy protocol is supposed to be https). When I use 'http' everything works fine -- even if I omit the scheme:// in the URL. Thanks for your response, very helpful!